# xv6 - what does '+' mean in a switch sentence

Tags: c, switch-statement, case, xv6

I'm modifying XV6 and i'm trying to understand something about trap.c

```
switch(tf->trapno){
  case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_TIMER:
    if(cpu->id == 0){
      acquire(&tickslock);
      ticks++;
      wakeup(&ticks);
      release(&tickslock);
    }
    lapiceoi();
    break;
  case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_IDE:
    ideintr();
    lapiceoi();
    break;
  case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_IDE+1:
    // Bochs generates spurious IDE1 interrupts.
    break;
  case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_KBD:
    kbdintr();
    lapiceoi();
    break;
  case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_COM1:
    uartintr();
    lapiceoi();
    break;
  case T_IRQ0 + 7:
  case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_SPURIOUS:
    cprintf("cpu%d: spurious interrupt at %x:%x\n",
            cpu->id, tf->cs, tf->eip);
    lapiceoi();
    break;

  //PAGEBREAK: 13
  default:
    if(proc == 0 || (tf->cs&3) == 0){
      // In kernel, it must be our mistake.
      cprintf("unexpected trap %d from cpu %d eip %x (cr2=0x%x)\n",
              tf->trapno, cpu->id, tf->eip, rcr2());
      panic("trap");
    }
    // In user space, assume process misbehaved.
    cprintf("pid %d %s: trap %d err %d on cpu %d "
            "eip 0x%x addr 0x%x--kill proc\n",
            proc->pid, proc->name, tf->trapno, tf->err, cpu->id, tf->eip, 
            rcr2());
    proc->killed = 1;
  }
```

when it says "case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_IDE" does that mean both of those must happen?

can a single process enter more than one case?

Comment: It is the same as `2+3`, the result is computed at compile time.

Comment: If the macros starting with `T_IRQ` correspond to different bits in the trap value, then yes, just those two, and no others, have to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does that mean both of those must happen?

No. The stuff between `case` and `:` must be a number. It doesn't matter that the number is specified as a sum, what matters the value of the sum.

> can a single process enter more than one case?

Mostly, no. Note that all sections of code, after each `case` keyword, contain `break` at the end. This will cause only one such section to execute. A small exception:

```
  case T_IRQ0 + 7:  // ***** Here *****
  case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_SPURIOUS:
    ...
    break;
```

The code `...` will be executed in two cases: when `tf->trapno` is equal to `T_IRQ0 + 7` or when it's equal to `T_IRQ0 + IRQ_SPURIOUS`. Technically, it enters the first `case`, does nothing and immediately enters the second `case`.

Comment: Answer to first part can also be yes. If `T_IRQ0` and `IRQ_KBD` are both interrupt flags, then the answer is yes: both interrupts must happen at the same time.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit It doesn't look so: `T_IRQ0` looks rather like "the index at which the IRQ counting starts". If `T_IRQ0` were a condition that could occur separately, the `default` part would handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The "+" is a normal addition. The resulting addition will decide if the corresponding case block is to be entered or not.